# NoForeignKeysError in sqlalchemy relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to learn how to use sqlalchemy relationships, and struggling so far.  I'm following the one-to-many example they have here:  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html

I'm using my own classes for my project, but the table and relationships are simple and fit this example nicely.  I'm attempting the bi-direcational relationship, so my code essentially looks like this:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('public.parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```

However, when I perform a query on Child I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2082, in _determine_joins
    consider_as_foreign_keys=consider_as_foreign_keys
  File "<string>", line 2, in join_condition
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 979, in _join_condition
    (a.description, b.description, hint))
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'parents' and 'children'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1399, in query
    return self._query_cls(entities, self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 140, in __init__
    self._set_entities(entities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 151, in _set_entities
    self._set_entity_selectables(self._entities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 181, in _set_entity_selectables
    ent.setup_entity(*d[entity])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3619, in setup_entity
    self._with_polymorphic = ext_info.with_polymorphic_mappers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 767, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1994, in _with_polymorphic_mappers
    configure_mappers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3013, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1811, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 184, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1656, in do_init
    self._setup_join_conditions()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1731, in _setup_join_conditions
    can_be_synced_fn=self._columns_are_mapped
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1998, in __init__
    self._determine_joins()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2103, in _determine_joins
    "specify a 'primaryjoin' expression." % self.prop)
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Parent.children - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

Honestly, this makes a lot of sense to me.  There are no foreign keys in the parent, even in the example.  I can see why it would error, but the sqlalchemy documentation says it's possible.  Any ideas?

Comment: Using the schema might be tripping it off. Try `ForeignKey('parent.id')`. About "there are no foreign keys in the parent": no, but there are foreign keys between the 2, so that's not the issue.

Comment: This indirectly fixed the issue. I added the schema to the ForeignKey declarations because I was getting errors with sqlalchemy unable to find the tables. The explicit schema declarations fixed that, but unknowingly broke the relationship stuff. It ends up all of this was due to me not importing the modules which contain the classes that the Foreign keys point to.  So importing modules and removing the schema declarations fixed everything.  Thank you!